# Diff chart with googleVis (R package)

Tags: r, googlevis

I would like to know if it is possible to create a diff chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart) with `googleVis` in R.

Comment: No, it's not. You can ask Markus to add the feature on GitHub if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I've created this function:

```
gvisDiffChart<-function(chart1, chart2)
{
  id1<-chart1$chartid
  id2<-chart2$chartid
  chart1$html$chart["jsData"]<-paste(chart1$html$chart["jsData"],chart2$html$chart["jsData"],"\n")
  drawFunction<-paste0("var data2 = gvisData",id2,"();\n var diffData = chart.computeDiff(data,data2);\n chart.draw(diffData,options); \n }")
  chart1$html$chart["jsDrawChart"]<-(gsub("chart.draw.+$",drawFunction,chart1$html$chart["jsDrawChart"]))
  return(chart1)
}
```

Then you call it inside renderGVis function, like below.

```
output$myTable <- renderGvis({
    c1<-gvisColumnChart(Population[which(Population$Rank==10),],xvar="Country",yvar = "Population")         
    c2<-gvisColumnChart(Population[which(Population$Rank==1),],xvar="Country",yvar = "Population")         
    gvisDiffChart(c1,c2)
})
```

It worked for me.